# ElasticSearch Kibana match_all

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nosql

I have the next problem: I made a python program and it was indexing a lot of domains (8000 per hour). Now i Have 16000 domains (more or less). In Kibana Discover window I can see my data but if I pick in Dev Tools and I make the query "match_all" I can only see 10 domains. Where is the problem?

I need to show all data in one query.

This is my actual query:

```
GET /project/_search
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 10 results because it's the default size for a query - you can see that information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html).

As is stated in the link, you can add the size argument with another value to see more information, but will be limited by the index.max_result_window which is 10000 by default.

What is the purpose of retrieving all information in one go?
The python modules available to interact with elasticsearch would allow you to retrieve all the information easily, see this [link](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) to see the **elasticsearch.helpers.scan** function.

Comment: ok, my problem was the "size" variable. It was telling me that I had 16000 data but only was showing me 10. Now it is working, thanks

Comment: If you follow the links I provided, the second gives you information about elasticsearch.helpers.scan python function, which you can use to retrieve all events. Depending on your use case, there might be other options, so please describe what you are trying to achieve by retrieving everything